# How do I assign a different field name for a query

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

In the query below, the first FROM retrieves the value of CodLabel where the value of CodRcdTyp = 'MGMAST'
The second FROM retrieves the value of CodLabel where the value of CodRcdTyp =  'PMTMAS'

How do I assign a different field name for the second CodLabel to use in my expression? Something like AS TypeCodLabel

```
SELECT
  tblDataActions.ApplicationNumber
  ,tblDataActions.CompletionDate
  ,tblDataActions.Actions
  ,tblDataPermit.ApplicationType
  ,tblDataActions.ActionStatus
  ,tblDataPermit.Type
  ,tblDataPermit.Applicant
  ,SysCod.CodRcdTyp
  ,SysCod.CodLabel

FROM
  SysCod
  INNER JOIN tblDataActions
    ON SysCod.CodCode = tblDataActions.ActionStatus
  INNER JOIN tblDataPermit
    ON tblDataPermit.ApplicationNumber = tblDataActions.ApplicationNumber
WHERE
  tblDataActions.ApplicationNumber = @ApplicationNumber
AND SysCod.CodRcdTyp = 'MGMAST'

FROM
  SysCod
  INNER JOIN tblDataPermit
    ON SysCod.CodOrder = tblDataPermit.Type
  INNER JOIN tblDataActions
    ON tblDataActions.ApplicationNumber = tblDataPermit.ApplicationNumber
WHERE
  tblDataActions.ApplicationNumber = @ApplicationNumber
AND SysCod.CodRcdTyp = 'PMTMAS'
```

Comment: I tried to resolve this by adding two additional DataSets, one for each CodRcdTyp value, but that results in retrieving the first CodRcdTyp value only, instead of the one it should be.

Comment: When I check the query results directly on the two additional DataSets they are correct. Why is the report resulting in what I described above?

Comment: You answered your own question - "`AS TypeCodLabel`"

Answer (score 0):

I had to set up the second DataSet Query like this:

```
SELECT
  SysCod.CodLabel
FROM
  SysCod
  INNER JOIN tblDataPermit
    ON  tblDataPermit.Type = SysCod.CodOrder
  INNER JOIN tblDataActions
    ON tblDataActions.ApplicationNumber = tblDataPermit.ApplicationNumber
WHERE  tblDataActions.ApplicationNumber = @ApplicationNumber
AND  CodRcdTyp = 'PMTMAS'
```

and the third DataSet Query like this:

```
SELECT
  SysCod.CodLabel
 ,SysCod.CodCode
FROM
  SysCod
INNER JOIN tblDataActions
    ON tblDataActions.ActionStatus = SysCod.CodCode
WHERE  tblDataActions.ApplicationNumber = @ApplicationNumber
AND CodRcdTyp = 'MGMAST'
```